# How to simulate a deck of cards in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

A dispenser can eject one of nine different items at random, simulating a deck of up to nine cards (as of 1.6 it is no longer biased toward certain slots). How would you simulate a deck of cards with more?

Note:

- A dice-type random generator isn't sufficient, since it doesn't simulate a card being removed from the deck on subsequent draws
- It would be beneficial to simulate arbitrary decks, not just a standard deck of playing cards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simulate a standard 52-card deck, you need to go through a number of steps:

- **Stage 1 - Suit selector**
  A dispenser containing 4 stacks of 13, corresponding to each deck. The item dispensed tells you what deck to go to for the next stage.
- **Stage 2 - High/Low**
  We can't proceed directly to choosing a card, since we don't have 13 slots in a dispenser, so insert a high/low selector here. This is another dispenser with 2 stacks, one of 6 and one of 7. 6 -> low, 7 -> high. You need one of each of these dispensers for each deck.
- **Stage 3 - Card selector**
  Finally, you can set up your final array of dispensers, containing the cards, 6 for low, 7 for high, again two dispensers for each deck. These dispensers only contain 6/7 unique items that correspond to the cards.

To use the card selector, first use the deck selector. It will pop out an item corresponding to which deck you should use. *Keep this item!*. Next, use the high/low selector for the deck you have been assigned. Again, *keep the item!*. Finally, remove your 'card' from the deck at the last round.

This method will simulate removing cards from the deck, as long as you don't take a wrong path (i.e. you are assigned spades at stage 1 and then go on to use the diamonds stage 2).

It is not *perfect*, since the odds at stage 2 are weighted in favour of high cards. There's no way round this (using dispensers) since 13 is a prime number.

As you can see, this method can be adapted to model non-standard decks.